# Unit test for Kotlin lambda callback

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, kotlin, mockito

Let's say we have the following function to test

```
fun loadData(dataId: Long, completion: (JsonElement?, Exception?) -> Unit) {
    underlayingApi.post(url = "some/rest/url",
            completion = { rawResult, exception ->
                val processedResult = processJson(rawResult)
                completion(processedResult, exception)
            })
}
```

It's clear to me how to mock, inject, stub and verify the calls to  `underlayingApi`.

**How to verify the result returned via** `completion(processedResult, exception)`**?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To test the lambdas behavior, the `underlayingApi` has to be mocked where the lambda is invoked via the `InvoactionOnMock` object like this.

```
    `when`(underlayingApi.post(eq("some/rest/url"),
                               any())).thenAnswer {
        val argument = it.arguments[1]
        val completion = argument as ((rawResult: String?, exception: Exception?) -> Unit)
        completion.invoke("result", null)
    }
```

This leads to the invocation of the callback within the object under test. Now to check if the callback out of the object under test is working verify it like that.

```
    objUnderTest.loadData(id,
                          { json, exception ->
                              assert....
                          })
```

Comment: With this you may get an "Unchecked Cast" lint warning. To prevent this, you may use the `getArgument()` function instead. For example: `val argument = it.getArgument<((rawResult: String?, exception: Exception?) -> Unit)>(1)`

Answer (score 10):

Building on Martin's answer, here is my approach without lint warnings:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.*

@Test
fun loadData() {
    val mockUnderlyingApi: UnderlayingApi = mock()
    val underTest = ClassBeingTested()
    underTest.underlayingApi = mockUnderlyingApi

    whenever(mockUnderlyingApi.post(eq("some/rest/url"), any())).thenAnswer {
        val completion = it.getArgument<((rawResult: String?, exception: Exception?) -> Unit)>(1)
        completion.invoke("result", null)
    }

    underTest.loadData(0L,
            { jsonElement, exception ->
                // Check whatever you need to check
                // on jsonElement an/or exception
            })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the most important line `import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.*`. Here is the library github : https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin. With the `2.1.0` version, just needed to change the import to `import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.*`

Comment: any() throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException